# How to find cURL Program Location

Tags: apache, curl, wamp

I am trying to install a module that required cURL.

I have already enabled php_curl from the php extensions.

But I need to be able to find the "cURL Program Location"

Where can that be found?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that it's been installed? You may have to do that first:

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Bob

Answer (score 0):

at first make sure that curl is installed on the server. Withou installed curl it gives no location.

you can search for the location with

> locate curl

Answer (score 0):

Normally curl extension is located in `ext` directory in PHP installation folder. You can also search to look for file `php_curl.dll`.